# Android phone won't connect to Computer

Tags: java, android, tcp, android-virtual-device, serversocket

I want to create an app. I need my computer (the Camera class) to send something to the app (which is acting as the client). It work's fine when I use my AVD. When I switch to my phone (Android 6), it doesn't connect. There is no error, but my computer stops at `server.accept()`. They are in the same Network.

This is the App-code:

```java
package com.whitespace.movement_detection_camera;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Connection().execute();
    }
    private void notification(View view, String text) {
        Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(view, text, 5000);
        View snackBarView = snackBar.getView();
        snackBar.show();
    }
    private class Connection extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            start();
            return null;
        }
    }
    private void start() {
        try {
            Socket phone = new Socket("192.168.178.25", 6657); // IP from my Computer (Camera class)
            DataInputStream receiver = new DataInputStream(phone.getInputStream());
            while(true) {
                String text = receiver.readUTF();
                notification(findViewById(R.id.area), "From Server:");
                notification(findViewById(R.id.area), text);
                if(false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            phone.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code on the Computer:

```java
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
public class Camera {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6657);
        Socket client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected!");
        text_sender = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

Edit: This question is becomming a connection problem so I am making a few changes.

Running `ping 192.168.178.14` (phone ip) from my pc returns `From 192.168.178.25 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable` (and a 100% package loss). Running `ping 192.168.178.25` (pc ip) on phone (termux app) gives me a 100% packet loss. I have two routers. The first one has the IP `192.168.178.1`, the second one has `192.168.178.2`. The .2 one provides the internet. I access both of them from my pc, but only the .1 from my phone. I was also using a VPN on my phone, but I disabled it and tried again, but it still wouldn't connect. By running `ping whitespace-ThinkPad-T420` on the phone, it knows that the ip of my pc is `192.168.178.25`, but again, there's the `Destination Host Unreachable` error.

Comment: Hello, can you try to ping your pc from your phone? Just to make sure that the connection is valid? As i doubt the issue is code related as it looks good to me. You can also download an app, TCPIP socket terminal and connect manually to the socket, thus you’ll be able to dispatch messages and print them out.

Comment: Using Termux and `ping 192.168.178.25` I get 100% package loss.

Comment: So, the phone can’t reach the pc, let’s try to debug it. Can you please access your local router and check the firewall?

Comment: I says enabled, but disabling it doesn't change anything.

Comment: if you are using windows, can you go to cmd and type ipconfig and paste in the results?

Comment: I use Linux. Typing `ifconfig` gives this output

enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:21:cc:72:1b:4c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf2500000-f2520000  

(1/3)

Comment: lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 843970  bytes 209415001 (209.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 843970  bytes 209415001 (209.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

(2/3)

Comment: wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.25  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::c56c:40d7:bbc6:a495  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:11:96:77:44:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1055287  bytes 1059192137 (1.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 638756  bytes 101706843 (101.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

(3/3)

Comment: Are you installing the app via adb?

Comment: No, I'm sending the APK in my Discord, nd downloading it from there.

Comment: Is your phone on WIFI or using mobile Internet?

Comment: @David Wasser WIFI, the same as my computer.

Comment: It is likely that your WIFI setup is preventing the mobile from contacting the PC. What IP address does your mobile get from the WIFI router?

Comment: My phone has 192.168.178.24, my pc 192.168.178.25